# How I can re-run preFetch on a quasar app

Tags: vue.js, quasar

I have the following routes:

```
organizer/groups/:groupId/dashboard
organizer/groups/:groupId/members/manage
organizer/groups/:groupId/messages
```

Each of these routes are encapsulated in a `GroupLayout` so that we don't need to fetch the group in every route and cache it for later usages:

```js
import { defineComponent, h, resolveComponent } from 'vue';
import { preFetch } from 'quasar/wrappers';
import useGroupStore from '@/stores/groups';
import { isError } from '@/boot/axios';
import { StatusCodes } from 'http-status-codes';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'GroupNavigationLayout',
  preFetch: preFetch(async ({ store, currentRoute, redirect }) => {
    const groupStore = useGroupStore(store);
    const groupId = currentRoute.params.groupId
      ? currentRoute.params.groupId as string
      : currentRoute.params.groupSlug as string;

    try {
      await groupStore.getActiveGroup(groupId);
    } catch (e) {
      if (isError(e, StatusCodes.NOT_FOUND)) {
        redirect({ path: '/not-found' });
      }
    }
  }),
  setup() {
      return h(resolveComponent('router-view'));
    };
  },
});
```

I have a problem that whenever the `:groupId` parameter changes, the `preFetch` function is not being re-run. I need to fetch the new group whenever the `groupId` is updated.

Is it possible to force Quasar to re-run the `preFetch` function when the `groupId` changes?

Comment: sounds like a job for a [watcher](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#watcheffect) and not preFetch

Comment: @yoduh yeah. I thought that as well but wasn't sure this was the best approach. Thanks